# Laravel scope with a user relationship to check subscription

Tags: laravel, scope, eloquent

So I have 2 models, `User` and `Website`.

I'm also using the Laravel cashier which uses stripe for subscription.

Relationship my `User` model:

```
public function websites() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Website');
}
```

Relationship in my `Website` model:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Also in my `Website` model:

```
public function scopeNeedsUpdate($query) {
    $query->whereRaw('last_queued <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 HOUR)')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
}
```

The scope is where I get the websites that need to be queued. However, I need to add a condition that it will only return a website is last_queued <= 12 hours AND the related `User` has an active subscription.

I don't really know the best way to approach to do it with eloquent.  Any way I try it ends up being way too messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to check for the existence of a relationship with some custom attributes you can [constrain your eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) with a closure. As you want to check for users with an active Stripe subscription, it would be cleanest to move that logic to a scope on your User model and then reference the scope in the closure:

User Model:

```
public function scopeSubscribed($query) {
    return $query->where('stripe_active', 1)
                 ->where(function($q) {
                     $q->where('subscription_ends_at', null)
                       ->orWhere('subscription_ends_at', '>', DB::raw('NOW()'));
                 });
}
```

This means you can now have a clean query.

```
Website::whereHas('user', function($query){
    $query->subscribed();
})->needsUpdate()->get();
```

Note that this is for Laravel 5.0. Cashier has changed quite a bit since then and [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/stripecashier-get-model-records-where-user-is-subscribed) has a nice solution for making `subscribed` into a scope for 5.2.

Comment: It's a little more than checking whether status is active, or `1` as Laravel stores it.  It also has a `subscription_ends_at` which has to be either `null` or a date that has not passed. (Grace period).  Laravel has a `$user->subscribed()` method that returns `true` or `false` so I was hoping to be able to use that directly somehow?

Comment: @zen I've not used Cashier before but I'm looking over the docs now and seeing what type of database tables it requires. It is not entirely clear what you want. To the best of my knowledge, are you wanting a list of websites with a `last_queued` field that has a timestamp in the last 12 hours and that belong to active users who are subscribed to *your site*, and whose subscriptions are active (`subscription_ends_at` is either null or a date that has not yet passed)?

Comment: yea that's pretty much it.  I'm using Laravel 5.0 and I believe cashier has changed after 5.1.  Those conditions you described are correct.  I was just saying it would probably be easier to utilize `$user->subscribed()` method since it does all the checking for you automatically.

Comment: Do you know how much Cashier has changed since 5.0? I mostly mean database structure. It looks like in 5.2 it adds some fields to the `users` table as well as adding a new `subscriptions` table. Is that true for you also, or are there only some fields added to the `users` table? Could you let me know what those fields are, or modify your post with them?

Comment: In 5.0, it adds several new fields to the `users` table including `stripe_active`, `stripe_id`, `stripe_subscription`, `last_four`, `trial_end_at`, and `subscription_ends_at`.  In Laravel 5.2, the subscription info is moved into a `subscriptions` table.

Comment: Okay that is helpful. Unfortunately you won't be able to use the default `$user->subscribed()` as it is not a scope or a query builder instance, but you can define your own scope that does the same thing. It appears to me that in order for a user to be subscribed to your site the `stripe_active` field must be true and `subscription_ends_at` is either null or a later date. Those seem like the only 2 conditions. Let me know if I am wrong, but I will go ahead and update my answer with a solution based on that assumption.

Comment: That is correct.  The `stripe_active` is either `0` or `1`, `1` being `true` of course.  And `subscription_ends_at` is either `null` or a later date.

Comment: Okay I updated the answer. It is obviously untested so please try it out first and let me know if it gets you where you want to go.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try it later.  One thing though, will that scope interfere with the `subscribed()` method with Laravel Cashier since they're named the same and both belong to the `User` model?  I guess I can just rename the scope if that's an issue but was curious about that.

Comment: No it won't because the scope method is actually called `scopeSubscribed` while the Cashier method is called `subscribed` so there would be no method name conflict. Even though you reference that scope method as `subscribed`, the query builder is doing some magic behind the scenes to changed the name to what it really is.

Comment: Awesome that works.  Just missing a `;` after the last `orWhere` statement, but otherwise good to go.  Thanks for your help!